# Martigale that maximizes its expected number of upcrossings/downcrossings

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $T\ge 1$ be some fixed integer. Consider a discrete-time martingale $(X_t)_{t=0,1,\ldots, T}$ or a continous-time martingale $(X_t)_{0\le t\le T}$ (the latter can be continuous or cadlag if it helps) s.t.

$$X_0=1/2 \quad\mbox{ and } \quad \mathbb P(X_T\in \{0,1\})=1.\quad\quad\quad (\ast)$$

For every (fixed) $\epsilon\in (0,1/2)$, denote by $U_{\epsilon}$ (resp. $D_{\epsilon}$) the number of upcrossing (resp. downcorssing) of $X$ accross $[1/2-\epsilon,1/2+\epsilon]$ over $[0,T]$, see e.g. 
[Upcrossings, Downcrossings, and Martingale Convergence](https://almostsuremath.com/2009/12/06/upcrossings-downcrossings-and-martingale-convergence/)
. Does there exist a martingale satisfying $(\ast)$ that maximizes $\mathbb E[U_{\epsilon}+D_{\epsilon}]$ (or $\mathbb E[\max(U_{\epsilon},D_{\epsilon})]$)?

Any answer, comments and references are highly appreciated.

PS : In view of Doob’s upcrossing/downcrossing lemma, one has

$$2\epsilon\mathbb E[U_{\epsilon}]\le \mathbb E[\max(1/2-\epsilon-X_T,0)]=1/4-\epsilon/2 \quad\mbox{and} \quad  2\epsilon\mathbb E[D_{\epsilon}]\le \mathbb E[\max(X_T-1/2+\epsilon,0)]= 1/4-\epsilon/2.$$

Could we expect the maximum is equal to $1/4\epsilon-1/2$?

Comment: This paper might be helpful : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.3169.pdf